# Direction doesn't seem to change with specific range of voltages

Tags: c

This program shows correctly the voltages but not specify the direction on the Hyperterminal. It keeps showing N for all the values of voltages. 
I've been trying but still couldn't find the bug.

Here's my code down below.

```
 // Using microcontroller AT89C51, ADC 0804 for display on hyperterminal
#include <reg51.h>
#include <string.h>

#define input P1

void delay(unsigned int time);
void SerTx(unsigned char x);
void SerTx_str(unsigned char msg[]);
void SerInit();
void convert(unsigned int p);
unsigned char msg[] ="Voltage= ";
sbit wint =P3^4;  


void main()
{

  unsigned int y,z,p;
    int d1,d2,d3;
    unsigned char buffer[10];


    SerInit();
    input=0xff;

    while(1)
    {
    wint=0;
    delay(1);
    wint=1;     
    delay(5);
    wint=0;     
    delay(10);
    z=input;


        y=z*2;   
        d1=y%10; 
        y=y/10;
        d2=y%10;
      d3=y/10;  

        buffer[0] =d3+48;
        buffer[1] =d2+48;
        buffer[2] =d1+48;

      SerTx_str(msg);
        SerTx_str(buffer);
        SerTx_str("  ");
        p=buffer;
        convert(p);


        SerTx(13);
        SerTx(13);
        delay(20);
        SerTx(10);


    }
}
```

Comment: `p = buffer; convert(p);` <- you're converting the address of the buffer?

Comment: no. The value in the buffer. By the way, I even tried with p=*buffer;

Comment: @Ruth: immibis is right: When you say `convert(p)`, you convert the address of the buffer. You probably want to `convert(2*z)`. Your `convert` function doesn't convert a string, it converts an integer.

Comment: What in your mind is `sbit wint =P3^4;` supposed to do?

Comment: Indent your code correctly!  Such sloppy style would land you an F.

Comment: You should try to convert buffer into an integer (as immibis sugested): `convert(atoi(buffer));` But before that you will need to add a termination char in `buffer`: `buffer[3] = '\0'`

Comment: @purplepsycho Or just, you know, `convert(z*2);`! Converting a number to a string and then converting the string back to a number is silly.

Comment: @chqrlie That might well be a language extension specific to this compiler. That sort of thing isn't uncommon in microcontroller programming.

Comment: Improve readability and remove the need for a comment by writing `'0'` instead of `48`

Comment: Thanks immibis. That is exactly where I went wrong. Why didn't it work when I gave     p=*buffer;  ?

Comment: @Ruth: You can answer that easily by looking at your own code: `*buffer` is `buffer[0]`, to which you have assigned `d3+48` earlier. So it holds a number between 48 and 57.

Comment: @chqrlie: Thank you for the suggestions. I connected write pin and intr pin to the same pin - P3.4. I did write the comment in the code.  And I did write my code readable.

Comment: @immibis: you are correct, what a poor syntactic choice.  `P3[4]` at least would not be ambiguous, but one more character.  Learn something new everyday `;-)`

Comment: @Ruth: Sorry to disagree, but indented as it is, it is not readable.

Comment: @chqrlie: P3^4 is the way keil takes. Making it as P3[4] gave me 4 errors and 0 warning when compiled. Sure. I can write as you said '0' instead of 48.

Comment: @Ruth: sorry for misleading you, P3^4 is the syntax extension supported by your environment for embedded development.  It is what it is, you have to use it the way it is.  I was commenting the toolkit developers' choice, not telling you of an alternative.

Comment: @ M Oehm: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = buffer;
```

Now `p` holds the address of `buffer` (because `buffer` is an array, this is short for `p = &buffer[0];`)

```
convert(p);
```

Now you convert the value in `p` - that is, you convert the address of `buffer`.

I'm guessing you want to convert the same number you're displaying? The number you're displaying is `z*2`, so just use:

```
convert(z*2);
```

Comment: Yes. I changed the code to                                                                                            p=z*2;
convert(p);   and here's the result:                                                      Voltage(dV) = 010  N
Voltage(dV) = 012  N
Voltage(dV) = 130  E
Voltage(dV) = 218  SE
Voltage(dV) = 256  S
Voltage(dV) = 308  SW
Voltage(dV) = 350  W
Voltage(dV) = 384  W
Voltage(dV) = 424  NW
Voltage(dV) = 490  N
Voltage(dV) = 502  N                                                                                                            Thanks for the explanation.